# Using local transport within current tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to deploy Carbon Application inside tenant on WSO2 ESB and use local transport between proxies. It looks to work fine when I use absolute URI with full domain e.g.:

```
local://services/t/my.domain.com/MyFirstProxy
```

And now I would like to pass message to another proxy in the same domain (tenant):

```
local://services/t/my.domain.com/MySecondProxy
```

I expect there should be posibility to refer second proxy either by relative path (without changing domain) e.g. local://services/MySecondProxy but if I try to use it this way ESB engine throws:

```
[2017-01-17 09:35:41,648] ERROR - CarbonContextDataHolder Trying to set the domain from my.domain.com to carbon.super
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set the domain from my.domain.com to carbon.super
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder.setTenantDomain(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1390)
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext.setTenantDomain(PrivilegedCarbonContext.java:152)
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext.setTenantDomain(PrivilegedCarbonContext.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CarbonContextConfigurator.invoke(CarbonContextConfigurator.java:33)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.transports.TenantTransportSender.invoke(TenantTransportSender.java:236)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:581)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:548)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:382)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:121)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:210)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doSOAP(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:281)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:226)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I need to deploy the same application in two separate domains independently and I don't want to use absolute paths as to be complicated in maintenance.

Is there a simple solution to use local transport without fixing domain name and use current domain by default?

Comment: Some kind of work-around could be creating Endpoint address dynamically using property with current tenant domain. Endpoint URI would look like this: _local://services/t/${domain}/MySecondProxy_. Property "domain" could be evaluated by extra class mediator and following code:

PrivilegedCarbonContext cc = PrivilegedCarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext();
String domain = cc.getTenantDomain();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you are using local transport within tenants in ESB. So u have to use absolute path when you are going to invoke tenant-based proxies.

You are getting an error, when you invoke proxy without domain as it going to assign it to carbon super.

FYI- If you want to make calls across tenants, you should use a non Local Transport even if they run from the same VM. [1] So it is not recommended to use local transport with tenants.

If you need you can use custom proxy path and refer documentation [2]

1. https://buddhimawijeweera.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/local-transport-in-wso2-esb/
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path

Comment: I understand that WSO2 works this way nonetheless I assume it could be a little bit more ergonomic using relative URIs as well. I don't actually need to make calls between tenants so it's a little bit complicated (but possible) to use local transport.